# Date format in pdf form fields exported from Libreoffice

Tags: forms, pdf, libreoffice, adobe-reader

Using LibreOffice Writer 7.5.4 to create pdf forms

I have created a date input field in Writer. When I enter a date via dropdown or manually, it is displayed in the Windows system format as `03.07.2023` - even if the entered format is "TT/MM/YY", but this is what I want in a German setting.

When I export the form to pdf and open it with Adobe Reader, dates are always displayed as 03/07/23 when entered from the dropdown.

Is there a way to force local format in Adobe Reader?